# replacing standard connection method in compiled SWT browser

Tags: browser, connection, swt

Do you know how can I override method which connects to page and sends headers in SWT Browser ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible, because the implementation of the SWT browser is actually a O/S-specific implementation. For instance, on Windows, the browser is actually Internet Exporer.

Perhaps there is some JavaScript way of getting it done.